# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: cnnCat2.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[Sublime Text Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUWbJ.png)

**Error Displaying**

```
2021-06-15 11:48:41.978235: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-06-15 11:48:41.978656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\washi\Desktop\Driver-drowsiness-detection-CNN-Keras-OpenCV-master\final.py", line 17, in <module>
    model = load_model('cnnCat2.h5')
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 206, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 109, in load
    meta_graph_def = loader_impl.parse_saved_model(path).meta_graphs[0]
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 113, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError(
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: cnnCat2.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
[Finished in 5.2s]
```

Run the final.py script with tensorflow as a backend, The script continuously monitors the the user's eye state and classifies whether the person is drowsy or not. model.py is the script used to training the CNN classifier model. but I get this type of error what should I do?

Comment: It is possible that you either do not have h5py installed (or it does not work, try importing it), or your .h5 file is corrupted so it is not detected as an HDF5 file.

Comment: Where did you save the model? As your screenshot applies, you have not ``cnnCat2.h5`` file in the working directory where your ``final.py`` file exist.

Comment: How can I install h5.py file?? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: I get this code on github and just run it, They do not have a cnnCat2.h5 file. @Kaveh

Comment: Here is a github link https://github.com/navinkumar357/Driver-drowsiness-detection-CNN-Keras-OpenCV.git plz share a solution.

Comment: I checked the link. Unfortunately, contrary to his claims, he has not published any model files!! @WashinWashi

Comment: You can find this model here (in the models folder): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zodAMJQFuqThN3sKQ9Bcb76gUSFIMPrG/view?usp=sharing  Download *.h5 and put it in the same folder which is final.py

Comment: Thank you @Kaveh. I will Check.

Answer (score 1):

in your code try to use `""` and not `''` in specifying the directory

for example

```
model_path = os.path.join(join(dirname(realpath(__file__))), "example.h5")
```